# Android multiple parcelable constructors

Tags: java, android, oop, parcelable

I have a object class that I need to have two constructors for it.
Ex.

```
//first constructor
public MyObject(int contract_id, String id, String title, String body) {
        super();
        this.contract_id = contract_id;
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }

//second constructor with extra parameters
public MyObject(int contract_id, String id, String title, String body,String time,String nickName) {
        super();
        this.contract_id = contract_id;
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
        this.time=time;
        this.nickName=nickName;
    }
```

The thing is that I know how to do parcelable for one objects that have one constructor, but what about this case? 
How should I recognize what constructor is called so I can create the right parcels?

Comment: you posted two ctors, and what now do you want to do?

Comment: @pskink if you read the question you will see this:  `How should I recognize what constructor is called so I can create the right parcels?`

Comment: so you want to know which ctor you used? so create a field set with a different value in every ctor

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Parcel.dataSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#dataSize%28%29) which

> Returns the total amount of data contained in the parcel.

or [Parcel.dataAvail()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#dataAvail%28%29)

> Returns the amount of data remaining to be read from the parcel. That
>   is, dataSize()-dataPosition().

F.e. define a constructor which takes a Parcel as parameter and check how much data is remaining:

```
MyObject(Parcel in) {

   this.contract_id = in.readInt();
   this.id = in.readString();
   this.title = in.readString();
   this.body = in.readString(); // till here both constructors have same data

   if (in.dataAvail() > 0) { // check for the extra data

       this.time = in.readString();
       this.nickName = in.readString();

   }
}
```

Use this constructor in your CREATOR like this:

```
   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
       public MyObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new MyObject(in); 
       }

       public MyObject[] newArray(int size) {
           return new MyObject[size];
       }
   };
```